# How to get real time user count of mobile app

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, flurry

We are having a launch party for our new mobile app on February 19th. At the party, we want to display a real time user count on a big tv (similar to the scene in The Social Network movie).

If someone creates an account on our app, we want to immediately see the user count go up by 1.

How do we do this? Flurry Analytics is not real time and that's our analytics platform. I've heard Google Analytics has a real time user count but can we have two analyics platforms at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, I created an account with Countly (www.count.ly) which is an open source analytics platform that tracks real time. We will hook my laptop up to a TV and zoom in on the user count portion of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes google analitics have great live report.

You can also take a look at parse.com

Parse Multi platform api make it super easy for you to create a app/web page to show live stats.

:)